# How to draw application architecture diagrams for Kusto using Visio?

Tags: azure, azure-functions, visio, azure-data-explorer, kql

My project mostly consists of azure functions and Kusto. Most of the processing is done in Kusto including different tables, update policies that use different Kusto functions, materialized views, etc. How can I represent all these features in Visio? I couldn't find any relevant examples.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the Visio "Azure" template, where you can find the "Azure Data Explorer (Kusto)" and "Azure function" icons as well as Icons for other services.

For the internal Kusto concepts such as tables, materialized views, update policies etc, you will need to use other icons from Visio.

Here is an example of the Azure icons (Azure Data Explorer, Table, function app) :
[image]

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I personally like [this collection of Visio stencil packs for Azure and Integrations](https://github.com/sandroasp/Microsoft-Integration-and-Azure-Stencils-Pack-for-Visio). The author updates them on a regular basis.